# try/catch block not working on express js

Tags: javascript, express

I try to create one route using express.js with a try/catch block, but when the conditions in the try block are not met, the code just loads without returning any value

any solution for this problem?

```
app.post('/test', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {name} = req.body;

    if (name === 'name') res.status(200).json({message: 'success!'}) // stuck at there
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({message: 'failed!'})
  }
})
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen when `name !== 'name'`? There's no code that does anything in that case ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not responding anything to the client in case `name !== 'name'`

Add an `else` with a response, or throw an exception that can be caught, and it should work as expected

Comment: thank you for your answer Haris. previously I thought the catch block was executed when all the conditions in the try block were not met.